# Get the project of a project level service in IntelliJ IDEA plugin

Tags: java, plugins, intellij-idea

I have a service class, which is registered in the plugin.xml as project level service:

```
<extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
    <projectService
            serviceInterface="MyService"
            serviceImplementation="MyService">
    </projectService>
</extensions>
```

I can get the project level service for the project myProject with:

```
ServiceManager.getService(myProject, MyService.class);
```

But how can I retrieve the project for which the service has been instantiated in the serviceclass MyService?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `Project project` as constructor parameter (it will be injected), then save it into a field.